# How to join two tables in SQL and get only 1 row per joining index

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, full-outer-join

If I have 3 tables like the following:

```
Table A:
Item Start_QTY
A    100
B    100
```

Table B:

```
Item Purchase_QTY
A    10
C    20
```

Table C:

```
Item End_QTY
A    90
B    10
C    10
```

How do I join the 2 tables to get the following result:

```
Item Start_QTY  Purchase_QTY  End_QTY
A    100  10 90
B    100  NULL 10
C    NULL 20 10
```

If I do the following:

```
Select COALESCE(a.item, b.item, c.item) as item, a.start_QTY, b.purchase_QTY, c.End_QTY from 
A as a 
full outer join 
B as b
on a.item = b.item
full outer join
C as c
on a.item = c.item
```

I get the following:

```
A 100 10 90
B 100 NULL 10
C NULL 20 NULL
C NULL NULL 10
```

Comment: What do you mean with "get only 1 row per joining index"?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MSSQL, But I want to to it both in MSSQL and MYSQL

Answer (score 4):

Use **FULL OUTER JOIN** to fetch all the data from both tables

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.Item, B.Item) AS Item, A.QTY, B.Price
FROM TableA A 
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.Item = B.Item;
```

**::EDIT::**

```
SELECT COALESCE(C.Item, A.Item, B.Item) AS Item, A.Start_QTY, B.Purchase_QTY, C.End_QTY
FROM TableC C  
FULL OUTER JOIN TableA A ON C.Item = A.Item
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON C.Item = B.Item;
```

Comment: wont this return
A 100 10
B 100 NULL
NULL NULL 20
?

Comment: I have updated my question to show you exactly what I am doing and what is being returned

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work in both SQL Server and MySQL, then you cannot use `full outer join`.  The following may do what you want:

```
select item, max(qty) as qty, max(price) as price
from (select item, qty, null as price
      from tablea 
      union all
      select item, null, price
      from tableb
     ) ab
group by item;
```

In SQL Server alone, you should use `full outer join`.